# TSQL Comma Separation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing an export function, where I need to export contacts to Excel, and I've run into a technical snag - or perhaps a gap in my SQL skills is closer to the truth. ;)

Here's the scenario:
I've got a bunch of contacts in a database. Each contact can have many different roles, for example a contact can be both C# Developer and DBA, or DBA and IT-manager. These are split into three tables, like so:

```
-------------------   -------------------   -------------------
*     Contact     *   *   ContactRole   *   *      Role       *
-------------------   -------------------   -------------------
* ID              *   * ContactID       *   * ID              *
* Name            *   * RoleID          *   * Name            *
* Address         *   -------------------   -------------------
-------------------
```

Not too hard to follow. There's a set of contacts, and a set of roles. These are joined by the ContactRole table on the respective IDs.

When I export the contacts, I need to have a column in the export with all the roles comma separated, like `C# Developer, DBA` or `DBA, IT-manager`. 
The export will be done from ASP.NET/C# codebehind, so I figured I could do this in code should it come to that, but I've got a feeling it's possible to do in the SQL.

The data comes from SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @Roles nvarchar(max)

select @Roles = case when @Roles is null then '' else @Roles + ', ' end + Role.Name
from  Role
inner join ContactRole on Role.ID = ContactRole.RoleID
where ContactRole.ContactID = @ContactID

select @Roles
```

update:

Above code covers functionality for a single contact. You can create a scalar function with parameter @ContactID and call the function from a

```
Select Name, dbo.GetContactRoles(ID) From Contact
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I'm after!

Comment: You may experience poor performance for big result sets, since SQL Server 2005 doesn't handle subqueries well, so you should monitor queries using this function.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, chopeen. I'm expecting result sets in the 500-2000 rows region, so I'm pretty sure performance won't be an issue. I'll make sure to keep my eyes on it, though.

Comment: @devio, You could also use the COALESCE function instead of the case statement: SELECT @Roles = COALESCE(@Roles + ', ', '') + Role.Name FROM ...

Answer (score 6):

Just because you use SQL Server 2005 (and if you are lucky and have all XML settings properly set), here is your simple SQL query (pure SQL and no functions):

```
SELECT  c.ID, c.Name, c.Address, 
    (   SELECT      r.Name + ','
        FROM        "ContactRole" cr
        INNER JOIN  "Role" r
                ON  cr.RoleID = r.ID
        WHERE       cr.ContactID = c.ID
        ORDER BY    r.ID --r.Name
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS "Roles"
FROM    "Contact" c
```

To test if it works for you, just execute the whole snippet below:

```
WITH "Contact" (ID, Name, Address) AS (
                SELECT 1, 'p1-no role', NULL
    UNION ALL   SELECT 2, 'p2-one role', NULL
    UNION ALL   SELECT 3, 'p3-two roles', NULL
)
, "Role" (ID, Name)AS (
                SELECT 1, 'teacher'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 2, 'student'
)
, "ContactRole" (ContactID, RoleID) AS (
                SELECT 2, 1
    UNION ALL   SELECT 3, 1
    UNION ALL   SELECT 3, 2
)

SELECT  c.ID, c.Name, c.Address, 
    (   SELECT      r.Name + ','
        FROM        "ContactRole" cr
        INNER JOIN  "Role" r
                ON  cr.RoleID = r.ID
        WHERE       cr.ContactID = c.ID
        ORDER BY    r.ID --r.Name
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS "Roles"
FROM    "Contact" c
```

and you should get the following result:

```
ID          Name         Address     Roles
----------- ------------ ----------- ------------------
1           p1-no role   NULL        NULL
2           p2-one role  NULL        teacher,
3           p3-two roles NULL        teacher,student,
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use **a CLR user-defined aggregate** to get such results. The user-defined aggregate can be invoked like the user-defined ones (e.g. SUM or MAX) and it doesn't use a cursor.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

[Serializable()]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.UserDefined,
    IsInvariantToNulls=true,
    IsInvariantToDuplicates=false,
    IsInvariantToOrder=false,
    MaxByteSize=8000)]
public class Concat : IBinarySerialize
{
    #region Private fields
    private string separator;
    private StringBuilder intermediateResult;
    #endregion

    #region IBinarySerialize members
    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        this.intermediateResult = new StringBuilder(r.ReadString());
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(this.intermediateResult.ToString());
    }
    #endregion

    #region Aggregation contract methods
    public void Init()
    {
        this.separator = ", ";
        this.intermediateResult = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlString pValue)
    {
        if (pValue.IsNull)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.intermediateResult.Length > 0)
        {
            this.intermediateResult.Append(this.separator);
        }
        this.intermediateResult.Append(pValue.Value);
    }

    public void Merge(Concat pOtherAggregate)
    {
        this.intermediateResult.Append(pOtherAggregate.intermediateResult);
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        return this.intermediateResult.ToString();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In [this posts](http://chopeen.blogspot.com/2007/05/sql-clr-user-defined-aggregate-notes-on.html) you'll find the code as well as my solution of debugging problems I encountered.

I used this aggregate in **production environment** and it performed really well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single query, though I don't know if the performance is good or bad.

```
SELECT [<group field 1>], [<group field 2>], [etc...], (
    SELECT CAST([<field to list>] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + 
        CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [<inner order-by REVERSED>]) = 1)
            THEN '' ELSE ',' END
        AS [text()]
    FROM [<inner table>]
    WHERE [<inner table join field>] = [<outer table join field>]
    AND [<inner conditions>]
    ORDER BY [<inner order-by>]
    FOR XML PATH('')) AS [<alias>]
FROM [<outer table]
WHERE [<outer conditions>]
```

That CASE statement inside is just to remove the last comma from the list--you have to ORDER BY something for the inner query and then *reverse* that ORDER BY in the CASE statement.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Query:

```
SELECT Contact.Name as cName, Role.Name as rName FROM Contact 
JOIN ContactRole ON (Contact.ID==ContactRole.ContactID)
JOIN Role ON  ON (Role.ID==ContactRole.RoleID)
```

Next proceed with application logic

```
forloop:
    array[ cName ] .= rName.', ';
endforloop;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Rewritten from table to scalar function based on [devio's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905818/tsql-comma-separation/905853#905853) so if you like this post vote for his answer.

If CLR integration is not an option, you can accomplish this with a scalar function:

```
create function dbo.getRole(
    @ContactId int)
returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
declare @Roles varchar(8000)

select 
    @Roles = case when @Roles is null then '' else @Roles + ', ' end + Role.Name
from Role
inner join ContactRole on Role.ID = ContactRole.RoleID
where ContactRole.ContactID = @ContactID

return @Roles
```

You can then call this function to calculate the comma-separated list for each contact:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, dbo.getRole(ID) as Roles
FROM Contact
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which outputs the roles as comma separated string when you pass it contact id.
Then call this function in your select statement :)

For example if you want to fetch products that are ordered by a customer in a particular order you can use this code:

```
    create function FetchProducts(@orderid int) returns varchar(1000)
    as
    begin
    declare prods cursor for select ProductName from products where 
            productid in (select ProductId from [Order Details] 
              Where OrderId = @orderid)

    open prods

    declare @products  varchar(1000)
    declare @cp varchar(500)
    Select @products = ''
    fetch prods into @cp

    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        SET @products = @products + ',' + @cp
        fetch prods into @cp
    end

    close prods
    deallocate prods

    return substring(@products, 2, len(@products)-1)
    end
```

now you can use the function as follows:

```
    select orderid, orderdate, dbo.FetchProducts(orderid) 
from orders where customerid = 'BERGS'
```