# SQL - Multiple rows into single column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to take the data output from the query below and join all of the email addresses together separated by a semicolon grouped by the employee name.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    p.email
    , e.name 
FROM
    PERSON p
INNER JOIN 
    EMPLOYEE e
ON 
    p.agentofrecord_id = e.employee_id 
WHERE 
    dbo.GetPersonMember(p.person_id) = 1
    AND (p.isactive = 1)
    AND p.email <> ''
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905818/tsql-comma-separation/913023#913023](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905818/tsql-comma-separation/913023#913023)

Comment: You are asking how to violate 1NF, which SQL isn't really designed to do e.g. the SQL Standard lacks a 'Concatenate' set function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Domains_and_values.

Comment: @onedaywhen - This is to get email addresses in a usable format grouped by employee...  Nothing else...  If I wasn't doing it here, it'd be code or excel...  Just looking for something easy to save some time later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, it looks like you want MySql's `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function in TSQL. If that's the case, [this article](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html) may help -- check it out!