# How to show multiple row values in comma separated in a single row in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Below I have shown two tables and also the result table.

[image]

How can I get the result table in this manner as I shown on above?

Comment: see the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value

Answer (score 6):

```
select min(ID) as ID,
       Val,
       stuff((select ','+Cat
              from Table2 as T2
              where T1.Val = T2.Val
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Cat
from Table2 as T1
group by Val
order by ID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0129d/2)

Comment: WOW.  That's impressive.  It's gone to take me a bit to parse it, but it works, inline, no clr, no scalar functions needed.  And now I know about SQL fiddle.  Twofer!!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
( 
 id INT
 ,Val VARCHAR(100)
)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
id INT
,Val VARCHAR(100)
,Cat VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES(1,'XYZ')

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES(2,'abc')

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES(1,'XYZ','a')

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES(1,'abc','e')

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES(1,'XYZ','b')

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES(1,'XYZ','f')

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES(1,'abc','g')


SELECT t1.id,t1.Val ,( SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + cat  FROM @Table2 t2 WHERE  t2.Val =                   t1.val FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))
 FROM   @Table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a **CLR user-defined aggregate** to do it. I posted a detailed description of such a solution as an answer to another question - [TSQL Comma Separation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/905849/95). There you'll also find a link to a blog post that discusses the problems you may encounter while developing a CLR aggregate.

After you deploy the custom aggregate to the server (I named the function `Concat` but yours may be named differently), you will be able to obtain the required result with the following query:

```
SELECT Val, dbo.Concat(Cat)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Val
```