# Asp.net c# multiple value in a single column of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

How can I show multiple value in a single column of a `GridView`? For example when I search "Ivan" in the `TextBox`, the output will return multiple rows of Ivan like this:

> **Name Task**
>   
> Ivan Task1
>   
> Ivan Task2
>   
> Ivan Task3

I want something like this

> **Name Task**
>   
> Ivan Task1, Task2, Task3

My Table is like this

> **Employee** (id,name)
>   
> **Task**(id,name)
>   
> **EmployeeTask**(employee.id,task.id)

Here is my sql code

```
SELECT  e.name,  t.name
FROM EmployeeTask et
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.id = et.employee_id
INNER JOIN task t ON t.id = et.task_id
WHERE e.name = @Name
```

And this is my `GridView` mark up

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="task" HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="task"/>        
</Columns>
```

Comment: How are you adding information to your table?

Comment: Check this. This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11126887/610194

Comment: Please can you copy a bit of your GridView code so I can get a idea how are you currently binding the columns

Comment: How are you accessing your data (Entity Framework, linq-to-sql, etc.)? There are multiple ways this can be done, so it would help to know.

Comment: While getting data from database you can concatenation.

Comment: @autumyst i manually add it to the sql server

Comment: @HatSoft i inserted the sample code of my program

Comment: @JamieSee i used sql statement

Comment: what is the return type - dataset, List<Employee>, etc

Comment: @tcoder i think it is dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure SQL, here's a way to get your desired result which you can then feed into the GridView:

```
SELECT     e.name, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
                          ((SELECT     t.name
                              FROM         EmployeeTask AS et INNER JOIN
                                                    task AS t ON t.id = et.task_id
                              WHERE     (et.employee_id = e.id)
                              FOR XML RAW(''), ELEMENTS)
                   , '</name><name>', ', '), '<name>', ''), '</name>', '') AS EmployeeTasks
FROM         employee AS e
WHERE     (e.name = @Name)
```

Essentially, it's a subquery that flattens the tasks into XML output and then replaces the tags with commas.

Comment: if i want to add a new line break after each task where should i use? i tried CHAR(10); but it gave me a syntax error

Comment: Modify the line as follows `, '</name><name>', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)), '<name>', ''), '</name>', '') AS EmployeeTasks`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your SQL query.

- If you are using MySQL you can use group_concat.
- If you are using MSSQL you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the Task name's using SQL something like this, mind you I have not tested the script

```
    DECLARE @CTasks VARCHAR(500)
    SET @CTasks = ''

    SELECT @CTasks = @CTasks  + t.Task + ', ' FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN Tasks t ON t.EmployeeId = e.Id
    WHERE e.Name = @Name
    ORDER BY e.Name ASC

    IF LEN(@CTasks) > 0
    SELECT @Name As Name, @CTasks As Tasks

You might end up getting a ',' at the end that needs taking care from Tasks column

Hope this helps...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Are using mssql server 2008 then 
 there is an introduction to the pivot functions which does the same thing 
you mentioned in the question

[How to Use Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Hope you find helpful

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle:

```
select name,wm_concat(task) as task from table name group by name
```

I dont know in sql Server.But i think it may help u.

[Similar Type Question, See it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621747/concat-field-value-to-string-in-sql-server)

In Sql:

```
SELECT Field1, Substring(Field2, 2, LEN(Field2)) AS Field2 FROM
(
    SELECT
        [InnerData].Field1,
        (SELECT  ',' + Field2 FROM @Fields WHERE Field1=[InnerData].Field1 FOR XML PATH('')) AS Field2
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM @Fields
        ) AS [InnerData]
) AS OuterData
```

I got this Query from Below link

[Refer this link](http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.in/2008/12/string-concatenation-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class:

```
Class EmployeeWithTask{ string employeeName{get;set} list<string>employeeTasks {get,set}}
```

Create an EmployeeWithTask list.after you retrive the list of tasks, for every distinct employee in the result loop through the results and create one instance of EmployeewithTask .
Finally bind the EmployeeWithTask list to your gridview