# Multiple rows to one comma-separated value in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-group-concat

I want to create a table valued function in SQL Server, which I want to return data in comma separated values.

For example table: `tbl`

```
ID | Value
---+-------
 1 | 100
 1 | 200
 1 | 300     
 1 | 400
```

Now when I execute the query using the function `Func1(value)`

```
SELECT Func1(Value) 
FROM tbl 
WHERE ID = 1
```

Output that I want is: `100,200,300,400`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Why is ID 1 for all rows? Usually ID is a Primary Key and is usually unique for each row.

Comment: SELECT Func1(Value) FROM tbl WHERE ID = 1
output: 100,200,300,400

Comment: The answer you want is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: A "splitter" would do the opposite .. split a single value apart to multiple values.

Comment: You can use string concatenation feature. I can't add answer (since it's locked), so I add answer here: `DECLARE @big_string varchar(max) = ''; SELECT @big_string += x.s + ',' FROM (VALUES ('string1'), ('string2'), ('string3')) AS x(s);`. Now show the result: `SELECT @big_string;`. It's that easy.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(ID INT, Value INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1,100),(1,200),(1,300),(1,400)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @Table1 
         WHERE ID = t.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM @Table1 t
GROUP BY ID
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║     List_Output     ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║  100, 200, 300, 400 ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╝
```

**SQL Server 2017 and Later Versions**

If you are working on SQL Server 2017 or later versions, you can use built-in SQL Server Function [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016) to create the comma delimited list:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(ID INT, Value INT);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1,100),(1,200),(1,300),(1,400);


SELECT ID , STRING_AGG([Value], ', ') AS List_Output
FROM @Table1
GROUP BY ID;
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║     List_Output     ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║  100, 200, 300, 400 ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: How can i use newline instead of ',' for separating the values?

Comment: I think it would be better to use the "COALESCE" function.

Comment: @A.R. what you actually meant to say: Microsoft's (non-)implementation of this and people's resulting workarounds are terrible by necessity. Don't just blame an amorphous 'all SQL' that doesn't practically exist.

Comment: This works but only issue is if you have "&" in your comma separated values (here List_Output) it will be converted to "&amp;" similarly with "<" &">".