# How to concatenate the different row values in to one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I have Table A with columns `CompetenceId`, `Description` and `Development Action`. This is Table A

[image]

I have another table B with CompetencyId and `Development Action`.

[image]

As each `CompetenceID` is having multiple development actions in table B. My requirement is 
for 'Table A'  I need 'Development action' column for a particular `competencyId` in the same row up on joining Table B. The result should look like below for Table A

[image]

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try using stuff: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=3934817c-1a03-4ac9-a0ba-55b2bfbaea0f&tkw=uses-of-the-stuff-string-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value