# Get all values from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help me with a SQL query. I would get all values, like '01,02,03,20,92,93,94"  values from first query, but instead of function MAX in two query. Result:in opposite b_BookNum I would to see one string:'01,02,03,20,92,93,94'

[image]

Comment: Please try to work a bit harder at explaining what you want.  Putting sample data and desired results into the question is a big help -- and much easier to read than an image.

Comment: Correct. Put sample data and expected data instead of showing some result.

Comment: Still not so clear to me. If you want them all then why are you even grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply take out the `MAX()` function and add this column in your group by clause , happy days......

```
SELECT  [b_BookNum]
       ,[b_CHMAT]
       ,COUNT(*) iCount
FROM MPA.dbo.SCHM_Books
GROUP BY [b_BookNum] ,[b_CHMAT]
ORDER BY [b_BookNum]
```

### EDIT

I am surprised that you have all the information you need to solve the problem and yet you are so incompetent to solve it. Anyway here is the full solution:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  [b_BookNum]
       ,COUNT(*) iCount
FROM MPA.dbo.SCHM_Books
GROUP BY [b_BookNum] 
)
SELECT [b_BookNum]
      ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST([b_CHMAT] AS VARCHAR(10))
      FROM dbo.SCHM_Books 
      WHERE [b_BookNum] = C.[b_BookNum]
      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
      .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS [b_CHMAT]
      ,iCount
FROM CTE C
```

Comment: In one string please

Comment: oh you mean comma delimited values ?

Comment: yes, i mean like '01,02,03,20,92,93,94"

Comment: Have a look at this [`Multiple rows to one comma-separated value`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value/21761267#21761267)

Comment: Error: Function "Stuff" needs 4 arguments

Comment: Your incompetence is shocking, who do you work for?

Comment: I no programmer in SQL. Thanks you very much!!!