# When Querying Many-To-Many Relationship in SQL, Return Multiple Connections As an Array In Single Row?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, join, junction-table

Basically, I have 3 tables, titles, providers, and provider_titles.

Let's say they look like this:

```
| title_id   |     title_name |
|------------|----------------|
| 1          |     San Andres |
| 2          |Human Centipede |
| 3          |    Zoolander 2 |
| 4          |    Hot Pursuit |

| provider_id|  provider_name |
|------------|----------------|
| 1          |           Hulu |
| 2          |        Netflix |
| 3          |   Amazon_Prime |
| 4          |         HBO_GO |

| provider_id|       title_id |
|------------|----------------|
| 1          |              1 |
| 1          |              2 |
| 2          |              1 |
| 3          |              1 |
| 3          |              3 |
| 4          |              4 |
```

So, clearly there are titles with multiple providers, yeah? Typical many-to-many so far.

So what I'm doing to query it is with a JOIN like the following:

`SELECT * FROM provider_title JOIN provider ON provider_title.provider_id = provider.provider_id JOIN title ON title.title_id = provider_title.title_id WHERE provider.name IN ('Netflix', 'HBO_GO', 'Hulu', 'Amazon_Prime')`

Ok, now to the actual issue. I don't want repeated title names back, but I do want all of the providers associated with the title. Let me explain with another table. Here is what I am getting back with the current query, as is:

```
| provider_id| provider_name | title_id | title_name    |
|------------|---------------|----------|---------------|
| 1          |          Hulu |         1|San Andreas    |
| 1          |          Hulu |         2|Human Centipede|
| 2          |       Netflix |         1|San Andreas    |
| 3          |  Amazon_Prime |         1|San Andreas    |
| 3          |  Amazon_prime |         3|Zoolander 2    |
| 4          |        HBO_GO |         4|Hot Pursuit    |
```

But what I really want would be something more like

```
| provider_id| provider_name               |title_id| title_name|
|------------|-----------------------------|--------|-----------|
| [1, 2, 3]  |[Hulu, Netflix, Amazon_Prime]|       1|San Andreas|
```

Meaning I only want distinct titles back, but I still want each title's associated providers. Is this *only* possible to do post-sql query with logic iterating through the returned rows?

Comment: these similar questions might help 
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator`

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your database engine, there may be an aggregation function to help achieve this.

For example, [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/de395/8) demonstrates the postgres [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) function:

```
SELECT  t.title_id,
        t.title_name,
        array_agg( p.provider_id ),
        array_agg( p.provider_name )
FROM    provider_title as pt
        JOIN 
        provider as p
        ON pt.provider_id = p.provider_id 
        JOIN title as t
        ON t.title_id = pt.title_id 
GROUP BY t.title_id,
        t.title_name
```

Other database engines have equivalents.  For example:

- mySQL has [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
- Oracle has [listagg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)
- sqlite has [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) (as well!)

If your database isn't covered by the above, you can google '[Your database engine] aggregate comma delimited string'