# Multiple rows to one comma-separated value different ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, sql-server-group-concat

> This question already has an answer here:
>   [Multiple rows to one comma-separated value [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value) *1 Answer*

I want to create a table valued function in SQL Server, which I want to return data in comma separated values.

For example table: `tbl`

```
ID | Value
---+-------
 1 | 100
 1 | 200
 1 | 300  
 2 | 600
 2 | 700
```

Now when I execute the query in SQL Server, I want table to be like:

```
ID | Value
---+-------
 1 | 100,200,300
 2 | 600,700
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(ID INT, Value INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1,100),(1,200),(1,300),(1,400)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @Table1 
         WHERE ID = t.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM @Table1 t
GROUP BY ID
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║     List_Output     ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║  100, 200, 300, 400 ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

Use STUFF method to get your result :

```
CREATE TABLE #table ( ID INT, Value INT)
INSERT INTO #table ( ID , Value )
SELECT  1 , 100 UNION ALL
SELECT   1 , 200 UNION ALL
SELECT  1 , 300   UNION ALL
SELECT  2 , 600 UNION ALL
SELECT  2 , 700

  SELECT ID , STUFF
 (
    (
     SELECT  ', ' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR)
     FROM #table Inr WHERE inr.ID = Otr.ID FOR XML PATH('')
     ),1,1,'') 
 FROM #table Otr
 GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE TABLE #Table1
        ([ID] int, [Value] int)
    ;

    INSERT INTO #Table1
        ([ID], [Value])
    VALUES
        (1, 100),
        (1, 200),
        (1, 300),
        (2, 600),
        (2, 700)



    select  id
       ,stuff((select ', ' + cast(value as varchar(10)) [text()]
         from #table1 
         where id = t.id
         for xml path(''), type)
        .value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,' ') value
from #table1 t
group by id
```

output

```
ID  Value
1    100, 200, 300
2    600, 700
```