# How to get multiple category for single product in list

Tags: mysql

I want to select category along with product i do have multiple category for the same product and i'm trying to display in list manner,

I did try using sub query and joins but i'm getting duplicate record for the same product

Result i'm expecting to get is comma seperated all category for the same product in one row

i'm trying to fetch data which should look as below

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
PRODUCT_NAME                          CATEGORY
--------------------------------------------------------------
Female Shoes - Blue color             Footwear, Sunglass
Female Sunglass Yellow color          Sunglass, Fashion, Eye protection
```

Here is my SQL Fiddle link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44dad2/1

Comment: What query have you tested so far?

Comment: i have did 

SELECT 
  P.PRODUCT_NAME,
  C.CATEGORY_NAME
FROM 
  PRODUCT_CATEGORY PC
  LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON (P.PRODUCT_ID = PC.PRODUCT_ID)
  LEFT JOIN CATEGORY C ON (C.CATEGORY_ID = PC.CATEGORY_ID)
ORDER BY 
  P.PRODUCT_NAME ASC (you can also refer fiddle )

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple rows to one comma-separated value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value)

Comment: no @Selvam i dont feel it's duplicate to your suggested answer

Comment: okay....i have retracted my flag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in MYSQL:

```
SELECT 
  P.PRODUCT_NAME,
  GROUP_CONCAT(C.CATEGORY_NAME separator ',')
FROM 
  PRODUCT_CATEGORY PC
  LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON (P.PRODUCT_ID = PC.PRODUCT_ID)
  LEFT JOIN CATEGORY C ON (C.CATEGORY_ID = PC.CATEGORY_ID)
GROUP BY
  P.PRODUCT_NAME
ORDER BY 
  P.PRODUCT_NAME ASC
```

in Oracle 11g:

```
SELECT 
  P.PRODUCT_NAME,
  wm_concat(C.CATEGORY_NAME)
FROM 
  PRODUCT_CATEGORY PC
  LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P ON (P.PRODUCT_ID = PC.PRODUCT_ID)
  LEFT JOIN CATEGORY C ON (C.CATEGORY_ID = PC.CATEGORY_ID)
GROUP BY
  P.PRODUCT_NAME
ORDER BY 
  P.PRODUCT_NAME ASC
```