# Sql query to merge multiple row data in one row

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

I have sample data in the format as given below

[image]

Now I want data in the format as below:

```
FirstName                Data 
Kallis                  10, 16, 17     
Sharon                  11, 13, 14, 15
Richard                  12
```

Please suggest the method or query so that i can get data in the above mentioned format.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MySQL? Oracle? PostgreSQL? MSSQL?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Something against MySQL? :P

Comment: in mysql you can use group_concat

Comment: in sql-server you can use the STUFF function, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value