# Convert a SQL Join Query statement into comma separated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to convert rows from a SQL Server database into comma-separated values but before I do that I need to look up an id value from a lookup table. The main table holds a index value and the lookup table has the text so my Select statement looks like,

```
 SELECT 
     dbo.tbProgramGrant.ProgramPercent, 
     dbo.tbProgramGrant.GrantFundingID, 
     dbo.tbProgram.Acronym
 FROM 
     dbo.tbProgram 
 INNER JOIN
     dbo.tbProgramGrant ON dbo.tbProgram.ProgramID = dbo.tbProgramGrant.ProgramID
```

If I save it as a view with the name `vwProgramCode` I can create my comma separated value using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p1.GrantFundingID, 
    STUFF ((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(p.Acronym) + ':' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), p.ProgramPercent)
            FROM vwProgramCode p  
            WHERE p.GrantFundingID = p1.GrantFundingID  
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS codelist
FROM
    vwProgramCode p1
GROUP BY
    p1.GrantFundingID
```

However I would prefer not to use the view but I can't get the syntax correct injecting the view Select statement in the Select stuff statement.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using `select @@version`

Comment: There is also another thread similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760969/multiple-rows-to-one-comma-separated-value-in-sql-server

Comment: @Rishi not really... OP is actually asking how to embed a view into their query, not how to concat a string.

Comment: select @@version -- both 2008- but being sun retired - but then 2016 and 2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT dbo.tbProgramGrant.ProgramPercent, dbo.tbProgramGrant.GrantFundingID, dbo.tbProgram.Acronym
    FROM dbo.tbProgram
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbProgramGrant ON dbo.tbProgram.ProgramID = dbo.tbProgramGrant.ProgramID
)
SELECT p1.GrantFundingID
    , STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(p.Acronym) +':' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), p.ProgramPercent)
        FROM cte  p  
        WHERE p.GrantFundingID = p1.GrantFundingID  
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS codelist
FROM cte p1
GROUP BY p1.GrantFundingID;
```